# Таймаут для opencv

Tags: python, opencv

я пытаюсь проверить подключение к потоку с помощью opencv:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(URI)
cap.isOpened()
```

и в данном случае таймаут по умолчанию 30 cек

как я могу установить таймаут без сборки ffmpeg, или подскажите пожалуйста простой аналог opencv где можно это сделать ?

Comment: Например, уменьшить время проверки подключения?

Comment: Да, какой либо таймаут

Comment: https://answers.opencv.org/question/50029/timeout-on-videocaptureopen0/